# Google App Engine: Multi-step Registration Form

Tags: python, google-app-engine, registration, jinja2, app-engine-ndb

I am hoping to create a 'multi-step' form for my 'job board' app. I'd like users to complete a resume (education, experience, skills) using a step-by-step form. I am mainly trying to avoid presenting a long, overwhelming form at once.

I have no idea how to get started. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this: http://thecodemine.org/#_demoForm=first - web form wizard.
You can prepare one handler in GAE with post method and use hidden input field to recognize page number.